# SSH No Matching Host Key Type Found

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, rsa

I have two servers,

- *S1*: My machine, *Windows 8*, *OpenSSH 8.8p1*, *OpenSSL 1.1.11* 2021-08-24,
- *S2*: A Remote Server, *Linux*, *Open SSH 5.3p1*, *OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips* 2013-02-11.

The message I have trying to investigate how to solve is

> Unable to negotiate with `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` port `xxxxx`: no matching host key found, Their offer ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

- Both S1 and S2 ssh users keys are **RSA-2048** (~372 chars),
- Both *S1* and *S2* `etc/config` files have all their options commented by default,
- Both *S1* and *S2* ssh users have their `config` and `authorized_keys` files identical, including both public keys and aliases,
- S2 is a Remote, Embedded Linux, not under my control, and which I cannot update. SSH cannot be updated, and is restricted to specific IPs.

Question is, should I change all keys to, i.e. ECDSA-256 for this to be solved?
Is there another configuration not mentioned here I am missing?

When I add the option `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`, suggested almost everywhere, SSH ask for password instead of checking the keys.

Comment: With `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` it asks for password -- so it _accepted_ the hostkey and your problem is _user_ authentication. OpenSSH 8.8 by default only uses for an RSA key the newer RSA-SHA2 algorithms, which 5.5 doesn't implement. **_Also_ add `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(expanding slightly)

You've actually fixed the problem in your title; with `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` it prompts for password, which means it *accepted* the hostkey. (You could even have told 8.8 to accept `ssh-dss` -- it's still implemented, although the OpenSSH developers recommend pretty strongly against it.)

The actual problem in your body is now *user* authentication, because OpenSSH 8.8 by default only uses for an RSA key the newer, stronger `rsa-sha2-*` algorithms, and 5.3 was about 8 years before those were defined. **Add `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`** to get 8.8 to use the old, weak algorithm 5.3 can handle.

And if possible make snide remarks to whoever is responsible for that ancient system you're connecting to :-)

Answer (score 6):

I have used this one, worked me best in my latest Mac OS X ( 13. 0 )

just do this  :

`nano ~/.ssh/config`

and put this text:

```
Host *
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

and `control` & `x` then select `yes` to save your edit.

Comment: How to limit this to one specific host?

Comment: Just replace `*` with your hostname or ip-address.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host whatever_alias
    Hostname real_hostname_to_your_server
    User your_remote_user
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```